# Make a dialogbox pop up when event fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make a dialogbox using jquery or javascript which should have two button one text line and cancel button on top right.

The box should look like below but it is pop up from right bottom side of our desktop.

Help me in code or suggest any useful link for this.
[image]

Comment: you mean Jquery ?

[dialogbox using java query]

Comment: Show your code if you have tried anything.

Comment: yes its jquery. and i have not tried anything because i did not get any specific way to do that if you have any link or code then help me. @ArjunTRaj

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali

Comment: have u seen https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_dialog.htm link? or u can directly set `$("div#dialog").dialog ({
  beforeclose : function (event)
  {
    if (!confirm ("Close dialog ?")) return false;
  }
});` as shown in https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jquery-ui/9781449325176/ch04s05.html

Comment: FYKI you can do this by simple css and html also using modal :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make using Jquery UI

Please try this sample

http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/9284/

```js
$("#showPopUp").click(function(){
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});


})
```

```css
body { font: normal normal normal 10px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

.ui-dialog-osx {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px; border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>



 <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
<p>Hello World!
</p>

<button id="showPopUp">
Open Popup
</button>
</button>

<div id="dialog-message" title="Important information" style="display:none">
    <span class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0;"></span></span>
    <div style="margin-left: 23px;">
        <p>
           SAMPLE SAMPLE
        </p></div>
</div>
```